# Как правильно сверять значение из SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Всем привет. У меня есть приложение календаря, и я туда решил добавить настройки фона всего приложения. Их я сохраняю с помощью  SharedPreferences в виде `String`. Например: пользователь хочет сделать фон приложения зелёным, и он для этого жмёт кнопку "Green". После этого в sharedpreferences записывается значение "green". Как мне сделать так, чтобы при запуске приложения, если значение равно "green", цвет фона приложения автоматически был зелёным? В коде, который будет ниже, я пытался сделать эту проверку, но почему-то условие не сработало. В чём может быть проблема?
Ещё раз повторяюсь, код ниже:

Options.java(активити, где я сохраняю значение):

```
package com.masterok.calendar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class Options extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static SharedPreferences pref;
    public static final String save_key = "save_key";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);
        init();
    }

    public void onClickGreen(View view) {
        ConstraintLayout options =  findViewById(R.id.options);
        options.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
        edit.putString(save_key,"green");
        edit.apply();
    }
    private void init(){
        pref = getSharedPreferences("Options", MODE_PRIVATE);
        pref.getString(save_key, "null");

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java(активити, где я делаю эту самую проверку, описанную в начале):

```
package com.masterok.calendar;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button notes;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Options.pref= getSharedPreferences("Options", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Options.pref.getString(Options.save_key, "null");
        if(Options.save_key.equals("green")){
            ConstraintLayout Calendar =  findViewById(R.id.Calendar);
            Calendar.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
```

Comment: уберите статические переменные и вам все станет ясно, цвет лучше сохранять как число.

Comment: `if(Options.save_key.equals("green"))` - ну так а что вы здесь проверяете, равна ли константа `save_key`( `= "save_key"`) литералу `"green"`? Конечно нет!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Options.pref.getString(Options.save_key, "null");
if(Options.save_key.equals("green")){
    ConstraintLayout Calendar =  findViewById(R.id.Calendar);
    Calendar.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

В этом куске кода вы просто проверяете наличие Options.save_key. И пытаетесь далее сравнить переменную Options.save_key с green. Вы должны получить переменную из pref и сравнивать уже её. Т.е.:

```
String _SK = Options.pref.getString(Options.save_key, "null");
if(_SK.equals("green")){
    ConstraintLayout Calendar =  findViewById(R.id.Calendar);
    Calendar.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```